# Using regex to only return some of the Loki Label values

Tags: grafana, grafana-loki

I am setting a Variable in Grafana.

I want to create a Query, that only returns a subset of the labels with value `app` the ones I want to return are those ending in `dev`

My Query so far, returns all of the labels with value `app` successfully.  However, I have been unable to successfully filter the values so that only `a-dev` `b-dev` and `c-dev` are returned.

How do I successfully apply regex (or alternative) to this query so that I can see the desired values?

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually figured out what I needed to do.  Originally I was trying to use `|` to run regex on the results from label_values.

However, this format worked:

```
label_values({app=~".*-dev$"}, app)
```

and returned only `a-dev b-dev c-dev` as expected.